# SQLServerException: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, numeric, mssql-jdbc

I have the stored procedure with the following signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc     
       @param1 varchar(4),           
       @param2 varchar(4),  
       @param3 bit, 
       @param4 decimal(14,4), 
       @param5 varchar(10)             
AS
...
```

In java side I have the following code:

```
StoredProcedureQuery proc= entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("my_proc");
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN);
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
...
proc.setParameter(4, new BigDecimal("10000"));
....
proc.execute()
```

When the code executes I see the following exception in trace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
....
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
....
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
```

But this exception sometimes throws and sometimes - not. Looks like it depends on something else. But I have not ideas what it may be.

Please, help to understand the reason of issue and provide possible solutions.

Comment: Just an idea to try: `proc.setParameter(4, new BigDecimal("10000.0000"));`

Comment: @agad 7 this change doesn't affect anything

Comment: Probably the problem is in SP. Show rest of code.

Comment: @lad2025 you are right

Answer (score 0):

Actually cause of the issue was inside the stored procedure.
Too huge number was inside procedure while intermediate calculations.